# shoppingCartOrder SOAP returns wrong orderid

Tags: cart, api, soap

When submitting an order via SOAP v2 shoppingCartOrder, the order completes fine and I can see it in the backend, however the order ID is wrong.

In the backend when an order is placed it increments the orderid from the last order placed, for example if the previous order was 1000003 the next order should be 1000004, however using the API it instead started from 0000001 and whenever I run the API it increments on a different counter, 000002, 000003, etc.

Does anyone know how I can make it use the same counter as the back/front end?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `storeId` field when making the request.
The request message should map to this wsdl message.

```
<message name="shoppingCartOrderRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="quoteId" type="xsd:int"/>
    <part name="storeId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="licenses" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
</message>
```

So set `storeId` to `1`.

Comment: Hi, this does indeed seem to be the issue, running SQL: select store_id, increment_last_id from eav_entity_store; shows two ids, '0' and '1'.

Comment: However after changing to this $orderID = $client->shoppingCartOrder($sessionID, $cartID, '1', null); I get the SoapFault Object:  [message:protected] => Can not make operation because quote is not exists. Note that when changing the storeId to 0 I do not get this message. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Ok changed to $cartID = $client->shoppingCartCreate($sessionID,'1'); and it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

You make the order in same store?

You can check the table: *eav_entity_store* ? in this table you can see the incrementid to any store